# How to invalidate/refresh observable manually?

Tags: angular, observable

I'm running angular 4.2.4 application, using **ngx-translate** for multilanguage capabilities. While translations of **static** text works fine, i also have some data that i need to fetch from api.

The api url looks like:
http://apiurl.com/endpoint/gb (where gb is the language i'm fetching)
I have managed to achieve an **update** of language once i change the page, but thats not enough.

Is there any way i could force to refresh ALL visible observables when i'm changing the language without changing page/page refresh?

My code (simplified) looks like:

ApiService.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class ApiService {
  baseUrl: 'http://apicall/fake/';
  lang = 'gb';
  constructor(public http: HttpClient) { }

  getGallery() {
    return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + 'gallery/' + this.lang);
  }

  changeLang(lang) {
    this.lang = lang;
    //some additional logic here for ngx-translate and such
  }
}
```

Page.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-page',
  templateUrl: './page.html'
})
export class AppPage {
  data;
  constructor(public api: ApiService) {
    this.api.getGallery().subscribe(data => this.data);
  }

  changeLang() {
    //change between several languages
    this.api.changeLang(lang);
  }
}
```

Page.html

```
<h1>{{'TITLE' | translate}}</h1>
<p>{{data}}</p>
<button (click)="api.changeLang()></button>
```

When i click on the button, only the h1 updates (with ngx-translate) and the p element doesnt update until i change the page and come back. What i want is to update the p when i click the button.

Comment: The question should contain the code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish, what you tried and where you failed.

Comment: Updated the question with some code.